# Как правильно сделать карточки? Почему position : relative не работает для img?

Tags: html, scss

В макете есть такой блок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как разместить текст поверх картинок, если картинка вставлена как `img`, а не через свойство `background`? Почему-то не работает свойство `position: relative` для картинки и контент карточек позиционируется абсолютно относительно обертки всего сайта. Вот разметка и стили

```css
.carts {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.carts__items {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
      justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
}

.carts__item {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 24%;
  flex-basis: 24%;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
  -ms-flex-align: end;
      align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 0 16px;

}

.carts__item-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
 object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.carts__item-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
      <section class="section carts">
            <div class="container carts__container">
                <div class="carts__items">
                    <div class="carts__item">
                        <img class="carts__item-img" src="./images/products/01.png" alt="">
                        <div class="carts__item-content">
                            <h3 class="carts__item-title">Portal TV</h3>
                            <p class="carts__item-text">
                                Smart video calling on the biggest screen in your home
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="link carts__item-link">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carts__item">
                        <img class="carts__item-img" src="./images/products/02.png" alt="">
                        <div class="carts__item-content">
                            <h3 class="carts__item-title">Portal</h3>
                            <p class="carts__item-text">
                                Smart video calling on a 10” HD display
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="link carts__item-link">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carts__item">
                        <img class="carts__item-img" src="./images/products/03.png" alt="">
                        <div class="carts__item-content">
                            <h3 class="carts__item-title">Portal+</h3>
                            <p class="carts__item-text">
                                Smart video calling on a 15.6” HD display
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="link carts__item-link">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carts__item">
                        <img class="carts__item-img" src="./images/products/04.png" alt="">
                        <div class="carts__item-content">
                            <h3 class="carts__item-title">Portal Mini</h3>
                            <p class="carts__item-text">
                                Smart video calling on an 8” HD display
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="link carts__item-link">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Вот стили scss

```
.carts {
    margin-top: $base * 25;
    &__items {
        display: flex;
        flex-basis: 100%;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
    &__item {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-basis: 24%;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: flex-end;
        padding: 0 $base * 4;
        position: relative;
    }
    &__item-img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        position: relative;
    }
    &__item-content {
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

Я назначил `position : ralative` для `.carts__item-img` и  `position : absolute` для `.carts__item-content`, но контент позиционируется не относительно карточки, а относительно обертки всего сайта. Вот скрин.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит? Как правильно сверстать такие карточки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы использовать возможность позиционировать элемент с position:absolute относительно элемента с position:relative, первый элемент должен быть дочерним элементов второго. С  так сделать невозможно. Надо блок карточки сделать relative, а блоки внутри, которые стоят в коде рядом с изображением, сделать absolute. Тогда можно спозиционировать надписи поверх картинки.

```css
.carts {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.carts__items {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
      justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
}

.carts__item {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 24%;
  flex-basis: 24%;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
  -ms-flex-align: end;
      align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 0 16px;

}

.carts__item-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
 object-fit: cover;

}

.carts__item-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="section carts">
            <div class="container carts__container">
                <div class="carts__items">
                    <div class="carts__item">
                        <img class="carts__item-img" src="./images/products/01.png" alt="">
                        <div class="carts__item-content">
                            <h3 class="carts__item-title">Portal TV</h3>
                            <p class="carts__item-text">
                                Smart video calling on the biggest screen in your home
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="link carts__item-link">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carts__item">
                        <img class="carts__item-img" src="./images/products/02.png" alt="">
                        <div class="carts__item-content">
                            <h3 class="carts__item-title">Portal</h3>
                            <p class="carts__item-text">
                                Smart video calling on a 10” HD display
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="link carts__item-link">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carts__item">
                        <img class="carts__item-img" src="./images/products/03.png" alt="">
                        <div class="carts__item-content">
                            <h3 class="carts__item-title">Portal+</h3>
                            <p class="carts__item-text">
                                Smart video calling on a 15.6” HD display
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="link carts__item-link">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carts__item">
                        <img class="carts__item-img" src="./images/products/04.png" alt="">
                        <div class="carts__item-content">
                            <h3 class="carts__item-title">Portal Mini</h3>
                            <p class="carts__item-text">
                                Smart video calling on an 8” HD display
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="link carts__item-link">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```